# Como implementar uma PushNotification

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Sei que eu necessito de um servidor de notificação para isso. Escolhi o firebase por ser gratuito e não necessita de cartão de crédito. O que eu quero fazer:

1) Quando o usuário alterar a Flag no banco, então um serviço vai pegar essa alteração e enviar para o servidor de mensagens e este disparar uma Notificação por Push.

Essa é a minha regra. Estou tentando fazer funcionar o meu e não funciona. Estou desinstalando os pacotes e deixar somente o que eu preciso. O erro que dá é: ***Unhandled exception occured.***
Minha Activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "Autorizador", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
         //global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        public static Context AppContext;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;

            CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>("840100012845");

            //CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();

            StartPushService();

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public static void StartPushService()
        {
            AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));

            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {

                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
                alarm.Cancel(pintent);
            }
        }

        public static void StopPushService()
        {
            AppContext.StopService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));
            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
                alarm.Cancel(pintent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Minh CrossPushNotificationListener

```
public class CrossPushNotificationListener : IPushNotificationListener
    {
        public CrossPushNotificationListener()
        {
        }

        public void OnError(string message, DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public void OnMessage(JObject values, DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public void OnRegistered(string token, DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public void OnUnregistered(DeviceType deviceType)
        {

        }

        public bool ShouldShowNotification()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Quando tento registrar o plugin no App.xaml.cs é que dá pau.

```
protected override void OnStart()
        {
              CrossPushNotification.Current.Unregister();
              CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();

        }
```

Comment: No firebase aparece o identificador/token de sua aplicação após você compilar?

Comment: No firebase sim, aparece. Eu copio inclusive o identificador e colo na aplicação. Acabei de fazer um outro projeto e startei e não deu erro, exatamente nesse momento. Acho que tem a ver com o serviço. Vou tentar enviar uma notificação e ver o que acontece.

Comment: E seu manifest, como está?! Configurado certinho?!

Comment: Sim, tipo: ***pt.empresa.autorizador.com*** esse é o nome no Manifest. Agora envio uma Mensagem, demora e depois dispara um erro de: **An unhandled exception occurred**, mas leva mais 8 ou 12 min para apresentar esse erro